# Outlook email (getting my emails in common account)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I am using 2010 Outlook and whenever I get a reply to my email, it automatically goes to common account (Customer Support: which has other 3 users attached to it) and not directed to me(only). Can somebody please let me know how to change that thing where I can get my email protected to me only and not to the common account. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might look at the "reply to:" address that is configure in your Outlook.

Whatever that is set to will be the recipient of any replies to emails you send out.

Make sure it is set to your "me(only)" email address and it will not go to everybody else.

Comment: Well, I have tried that thing. Also, I have compared settings with other accounts as well. Seems fine. But only my account doesn't get the email to me when someone reply.

Comment: Then you probably need to describe your problem better.  Based on the very limited amount of information you have provided, this is about all the help you can expect.  No?  My knee hurts, how do I stop it from hurting?

Comment: I do not know much about IT terms and that is the issue I am unable to make you understand. I will try to explain in a described way if you are able to understand it. I have a business and 4 of my workstations have attached to one group email id which is for customer support. So it is supposed to work like this. "When someone send an email to someone, it goes from the personal email id and get the reply back into it. And when someone get the email and reply back, it goes from the personal email id." But one of the workstations is not working that way.

Comment: When it sends an email, it goes well but when the same email gets replied, it goes to customer support and not to the one who sent it actually. Please reply if you understood or not because that was the best way I could try.